# ¿Cómo cargar un Fragment dentro de un AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-studio, alertdialog

Me parecía algo tan fácil de hacer pero no me fue.
Mi problema es que quiero cargar en un AlertDialog un Fragment de chat.
El método chatDialog() lo llamo cuando hago clic en un botón...

```
private void chatDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogo_comentario, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    TextView btnRegresar = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.regresar);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Agregue su comentario");
    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();

    //Aqui esta el problema al intentar cargar dentro del "CONTENEDOR" 
    Contenedor_Comentarios fragment = new Contenedor_Comentarios();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.CONTENEDOR,fragment).commit();

    btnRegresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            b.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

Y el layout dialogo_comentario es así

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/regresar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Cerrar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/CONTENEDOR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Quieres que el fragment se muestre dentro del AlertDialog o quieres que el Alert abra un fragment?

Comment: Que el Fragment "Contenedor_Comentarios" se abra dentro del AlertDialog. Para que el fragment reemplace el "id/CONTENEDOR" del layout del AlertDialog.